# Model binder woes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, modelbinders

why do I always have so much trouble with the model binder??  I have the following controller:

```
namespace X.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ExpertsVM
    {
        public string GivenName;
        public string Surname;
    }

    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterExpert(ExpertsVM v)
        {
```

and my view looks like this:

```
@using X.Web.Controllers
@model ExpertsVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterExpert", "Auth"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.GivenName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Surname)
```

so the form gets rendered like this:

```
<form action="/Auth/RegisterExpert" method="post">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="GivenName" name="GivenName" type="text" value="" />
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text" value="" />
```

but when the action gets invoked, `v` contains all nulls.  if I declare the action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterExpert(FormCollection f)
{
```

I see all the values... so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of Asp.Net MVC are you using ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I would use property instead of public field.

try

```
public class ExpertsVM
{
    public string GivenName {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: My +1 comes from solving the exact same problem yesterday!

Comment: son of a biscuit! it's the first time I do it like that.  thanks a lot (you get an uptick)

Answer (score 2):

The model binder looks for public properties on the model. VdesmedT's answer is right, but I am adding this to add emphasis to the point (he wasn't 100% sure, I am).

You could also spare yourself one of the using statments by doing:

```
@model X.Web.Controllers.ExpertsVM
```

I have upvoted VdesmedT's answser.  You should mark that as the answer.